How to properly prune a YOLO detection model
I am trying to prune a Yolov8 detection model, using this snippet. But when I load the pruned model, it still shows the same number of parameters (3,011,048 parameters). I'm not sure if I'm doing this in the right way.
My question is, is my pruning process correct? And once I save the model, should I fine-tune it with the dataset again?
Snippet to prune:
import torch
from torch.nn.utils import prune
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('best.pt')
ratio = 0.25
numbers_to_check = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for name, module in model.named_modules():
    print(name)
for name, module in model.named_modules():
    if ("cv1.conv" in name or "cv2.conv" in name) and any("."+str(num)+"." in name for num in numbers_to_check):
        print(f"Pruning layer (ratio: {ratio}): {name}")
        prune.l1_unstructured(module, name='weight', amount=ratio)
        prune.remove(module, 'weight')

model.save(f'pruned_model.pt')


Unstructured pruning (which you're using) just sets small weights to 0, but doesn't reduce the dimension size of the layers, which is why you are not seeing a reduction in size. See this Github comment.

As is, this module is not intended (by itself) to help you with memory savings. All that pruning does is to replace some entries with zeroes. This itself doesn't buy you anything, unless you represent the sparse tensor in a smarter way (which this module itself doesn't handle for you).

And yes, fine-tuning after pruning is a standard practice (source) to improve the accuracy of the model.

Thanks. Is it fair to say most likely a fine-tuned pruned model would perform better that the original model?

Not necessarily. Pruning might actually hurt the model's prediction quality and fine tuning can enhance it. We can't say for sure that the model will be better in the end.
